# Use projection with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, projection

I use spring boot and spring data.
In a REST application when I called my GET web service in the following form "http://localhost:8080/project/api/persons" I get the list of all the persons in my database by displaying only just the information related to the person like fisrtname and lastname  and not the objects they are in connection with him eg address (Address is another entity in my project).
So I used a projection to also display the information related to the address against when I call with the following link "http://localhost:8080/project/api/persons1?Projection=resumePerson" I would have sought result. However, with the following link "http://localhost:8080/project/api/persons?Projection=resumePerson" address information is always invisible.

```
 public class Person {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String lastname;

  private String firstname;

  @OneToMany
  List<Address> address;

}

public class Address {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String rue;

  private String code;


  private String country;

}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "persons", path = "persons", excerptProjection = ResumePerson.class)
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

}

@Projection(name = "resumePerson", types = { Person.class })
interface ResumePerson {
    String getFirstname();

    String getLastname();

    List<Address> getAddress();
}
```

Resultats of GET web services.
http://localhost:8080/project/api/persons and http://localhost:8080/project/api/persons?projection=resumePerson

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "firstname" : "firstname_1",
      "lastname" : "lastname_1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/si-ice/api/persons/1{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "address" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/si-ice/api/agents/1/address"
        },
      }
    },
    {
      "firstname" : "firstname_2",
      "lastname" : "lastname_2",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/si-ice/api/persons/2{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "address" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/si-ice/api/agents/2/address"
        },
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

and with http://localhost:8080/project/api/persons/1?projection=resumePerson

```
{
      "firstname" : "firstname_1",
      "lastname" : "lastname_1",
      "Address" : {
          "rue" : "RUE_1",
          "code" : "CODE_1",
          "country" : "COUNTRY_1"
      },          
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/si-ice/api/persons/1{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "address" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/si-ice/api/agents/1/address"
        },
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using in the controller and the data layer. Thanks

Comment: please add the code used to get the list of Persons, and also check that your beans are written correctly: getters and setters